# appcelerator: Ti.Geolocation.reverseGeocoder crashes app

Tags: ios, geolocation, appcelerator-titanium

I'm running code to determine the name of city of the user's current location.

Whenever I call the reverseGeocoder the app immediatly crashes, even by just calling it with hardcoded coordinates.

```
Ti.Geolocation.reverseGeocoder(50,50, function(e) {
    console.log('reverse encoding result:',e);
});
```

The error is:

```
[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      column = 35;
[ERROR] :      line = 338;
[ERROR] :      message = "*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[5]";
```

pointing to the code above calling the encoder.
Using Titanium SDK 8.2.0, XCode 11.1, OSX 10.14.5
The issue happens in the emulator and on the device.
This issue does not occur on android for me.